# Absolute and relative importing for scripts

Tags: python, import, relative-import

I know this question has been asked often but I have a very specific problem concerning importing. I have a file structure as follows:

```
main/main.py
main/test_device.py
main/lib/instructions.py
main/device/android.py
main/temp/example.py
```

Basically, what's happening here is that my program (`main.py`) creates several smaller scripts (in `temp/`) and then attempts to run them. However, each of these scripts references `lib/instructions.py` and `device/android.py`. This code runs these files:

```
name = "temp/test_" + str(program_name) + ".py"
input_file = open("test_device.py", "r")
contents = input_file.readlines()
input_file.close()
contents.insert(7, "program = [" + ", ".join(str(i) for i in instructions) + "]\r\n")
contents.insert(8, "count = " + str(program_name) + "\r\n")
contents = "".join(contents)
input_file = open(name, "w+")
input_file.write(contents)
Popen("python " + name)
```

I have `__init__.py` files in every directory but because these files are scripts, I can't use relative imports. How would I go about importing these libraries?

Comment: Show us the code you use to run the scripts in the `temp` dir.

Comment: @Sevanteri I've uploaded the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I'm understanding you, you need the script you're building in contents to be able to import the other modules from your package, but it can't ask for the right target directory b/c its kind of an awkward relative import above itself. try adding this line before you join the list together

```
contents.insert(0, "import sys; sys.path.append('lib'); sys.path.append('device')")
```

it's late over here & I'm on my phone so there may be a typo, but I'm hoping that'll work for you.

edit: depending on which is the present working directory, you might need to append '../lib' or use an absolute path

Comment: I don't particularly like using `sys` this way but I guess it can't be helped. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: you're welcome. yeah, I guess the way it's named it almost sounds like you'd be making a system wide settings change, but really the change just affects the namespace where you do it & it's not persistent

Answer (score 1):

Copying your modules to python/lib/site-packages would solve the issue.